# Discord.py on_voice_state_update dont work

Tags: python, discord.py

I have a problem that I cannot fix. First of all, I just want to print out the number 1 when someone joins a voice channel. To the best of my knowledge, you do this with the on_voice_state_update method. But for some reason my code doesn't work. Can someone tell me what I did wrong

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import asyncio
import DiscordUtils
from discord.ext.commands import has_permissions

class Example(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, client):
        self.client = client

    @commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_ready(self):
        print("test is loaded!")

    @commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_voice_state_update(self, member, before, after):
        print("1")

def setup(client):
    client.add_cog(Example(client))
```

Comment: The code works fine when I test it. How are you loading the cog?

Comment: do you have the default Intents?

Comment: Every other Cog I use works perfectly, exept this one so i dont think that this is the issue.

Comment: I have every intents set to True